# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint . The statement has been terminated

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_T_OrderDetails_T_SelectionList". The conflict occurred in database "AlbumPortal", table "dbo.T_SelectionList", column 'ID'.

I am new to ASP.NET MVC with EF code-first approach, I get this error when trying to save data to `T_OrderDetails` from controller.

In `T_OrderDetails` table 'SelectionList_ID' is foreign key from the table `dbo.T_SelectionList`. For that it is defined as

```
public virtual T_SelectionList T_SelectionList { get; set; }
```

in 'T_OrderDetails' and

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<T_OrderDetails> T_OrderDetails { get; set; }
```

in 'T_SelectionList'. Also

```
modelBuilder.Entity<T_SelectionList>()
                .HasMany(e => e.T_OrderDetails)
                .WithOptional(e => e.T_SelectionList)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.SelectionList_ID);
```

is defined. Then I don't understand why this error getting.

Comment: most likely, when you insert your data, the FK is different from the ID value of the referenced table. You should match these values, I mostly had the problem that the FK value was NULL while the Id value was 0. set both columns to the same value, and the entry will be saved correctly.

Comment: yes ,that was my problem.Thank you DevilSuichiro